# Display certain amount of posts on taxonomy archive page

Tags: php, wp-query, taxonomy, terms

I have a taxonomy archive page where I display everything under the term 'techno' I want to be able to limit this to 20 posts to a page until it paginates. At the moment it displays 10 on one page and then 10 on another. This works fine on my main page where I give the posts per page limit to 20. Can anyone see why? Here is my code

```
<?php

/*

Template Name: Genre

*/

//Protect against arbitrary paged values
$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? absint( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) : 1; 

get_header();

$object = get_queried_object();

$taxonomy = "genre"; // can be category, post_tag, or custom taxonomy name

// Using Term Slug
$term_slug = $object->slug;
$term = get_term_by('slug', $term_slug, $taxonomy);

// Fetch the count
$number = $term->count / 20;



?>
<header class="intro-archive">
        <div class="intro-body">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                        <h1 class="brand-heading"><?php echo $object->name; ?></h1>

                        <p class="intro-text">An archive of all the <?php echo $object->name; ?> posted on the site</p><a class="btn btn-circle page-scroll fa fa-angle-double-down animated" href="#latest" style="font-size:54px;"></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header><!-- About Section -->

    <section class="container content-section text-center" id="latest">

        <?php 
        $j = 0;

         if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); // standard WordPress loop.

              $thumb_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();
              $thumb_url_array = wp_get_attachment_image_src($thumb_id, '370x250' );
              $thumb_url = $thumb_url_array[0];

              // Grab the artist ID from the post meta
              $artist = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '_artist');

              // seperate each artist id
              $explodeArray = array_filter(explode(' ', $artist[0]));

              $arrayLength = count($explodeArray);

              $i = 0;

              // If there is more than one artist attached to song loop through
              if ($arrayLength > 1) {
                foreach ($explodeArray as $array) {
                  $artist_meta[$i] = get_the_title($array);
                  $i++; 
                }
              } else {
                $artist_name = get_the_title($explodeArray[0]);
              }

              // If the current counter dividied by 4 leaves no remainder add a row
              // This splits our archive into rows with 4 elements in
              if($j % 4 == 0) { ?> 

              <div class="row ">

              <?php } ?>

                  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12" style="margin-top:100px;">
                        <div class="ih-item square effect3 bottom_to_top">
                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                                <div class="img">
                                    <img alt="" class="image-responsive" src="<?php echo $thumb_url ?>">
                                </div>
                                <div class="info">
                                    <h3><?php if ($artist_meta) { foreach($artist_meta as $meta) { echo $meta; echo '<br />'; } } else { echo $artist_name; } ?></h3>
                                    <p><?php the_title(); ?></p>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                   </div>

               <?php 
                $j++;

                if ( $j != 0 && $j % 4 == 0 ) { ?>

                </div><!--/.row-->
                <?php 
                }

                endwhile; endif;
                ?>
               <div class="col-md-12">
                  <?php dem_pagination($number); ?>
               </div>
            </div>
        </section><!-- Footer -->

    <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe a very quick and (simplified)dirty way I show here, but would this function not solve it without the need to make changes for/in the templates?
*(Yes I know I also make queries in my templates but wanted to help out before leaving office)*

```
function wpse214084_max_post_queries( $query ) {

   if(is_tax('genre')){ // change genre into your taxonomy or leave out for all
     // show 20 posts
     $query->set('posts_per_page', 20);
   }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse214084_max_post_queries' );
```

> FYI: Maybe you take a look at
>   [`pre_get_posts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts)in
>   the codex and also at
>   [`is_tax`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_tax).
>   What you probably where/am looking for is [query
>   posts](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts)
>   **post_per_page**.

I hope this helps you out or at least gives some guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

i back @Charles answer, along with that another workaround is to create new object of WP_Query class, and use that object's loop instead of default loop,

Dont forget to use

> $wp_query->query_vars['taxonomy_name']

to get the current taxanomy and load it into WP_Query's object parameters.
with that you can use posts_per_page.

more details [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)