# Set the limit of taxonomy per page

Tags: taxonomy

```
 $ency_args = array(
'taxonomy'   => 'mycategory',
'orderby'    => 'name',
'order'      => 'ASC',
'hide_empty' => false,
'posts_per_page'    => 6,
```

how can i set the limit of showing of taxonomies in this situation, because post_per_page doesn't work? I want to show by default 6 taxonomies.

Comment: Use `'number' => 6` instead of `posts_per_page` and check

Comment: You trying to show 6 posts from the taxonomy called "mycategory"?

Comment: See my answer [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/214096/15605) *if that is the answer you are looking for give it an up-vote also please.*